# How can I make VS Code focus an existing editor tab in another group instead of opening a new one in the active group?

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-code

I'm not sure if this is possible, and wasn't sure where to even begin looking.  Thought the community would be better suited to give ideas or suggestions on how to achieve this.

I have a split screen setup with a single VSCode window.  I noticed that the same exact file, when opened on a tab on the left pane, can also be re-opened with another tab on the right pane - at the same time.

Is there a way to specify a behavior or setting where, whenever I `cmd + p` and open a file that already has an existing tab, I can bring that existing tab to the foreground instead of opening another one?

Comment: If your question is answered, remember to accept it. Or let us know how the existing answer doesn't help so we can improve it.

Answer (score 23):

You can configure `"workbench.editor.revealIfOpen": true` in settings to always reveal a file if already opened in any other group.

Comment: Strange to not have this as default. I always end up with the same file open in multiple split panel tabs.

Comment: A more user-friendly approach is to access and change the setting by following these steps:  `File > Preferences > Settings`. At the top of that tab, type this into the search: "reveal if open". Check that box.

Comment: Depressingly, Windows / Ubuntu / Mac do these differently (as always). On the Mac it's Preferences > Settings.
Also, this setting seems rather inconsistent. It works some of the time.